# Optimize performance of flatten function in python

Tags: python, performance, hash-map

I have to flatten a large number (>300k) dicts to write them to a csv file.

Example:

```
dict = {
    a: b,
    c: [
       {
           d:e
       },
       {
           f:g
       }  
    ]
}
```

becomes:

```
a, c.0.d, c.1.f
b, e, g
```

The dicts can be really big with a lot of dicts as values.

My function to flatten them generically is:

```
def flatten(self, d, parent_key='', sep='.'):
        items = []
        for k, v in d.items():
            new_key = parent_key + sep + k if parent_key else k
            if isinstance(v, collections.MutableMapping):
                items.extend(self.flatten(v, new_key, sep=sep).items())
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                if isinstance(v[0], dict):
                    counter = 0
                    for entry in v:
                        new_count_key = new_key + sep + str(counter)
                        items.extend(self.flatten(entry, new_count_key, sep=sep).items())
                        counter += 1
                else:
                    items.append((new_key, v))
                    if new_key not in self.key_list:
                        self.key_list.append(new_key)
            else:
                items.append((new_key, v))
                if new_key not in self.key_list:
                    self.key_list.append(new_key)
        return dict(items)
```

When I meassure the time needed for exceution I found out the highest amount of time is caused by the instance checks. With 2500 dicts for example, the instance checks need around 6 seconds out of 12 seconds total.

Is there any way, I can speed up this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One avenue to try improve your speed is to use the Pythonic principle that it's *Easier to Ask Forgiveness than beg Permission*. This means that instead of testing your data every single time, you should just assume that it's in the correct form and catch the errors when you've gotten it wrong.

For instance, you test your dictionary here:

```
if isinstance(v[0], dict):
    counter = 0
    for entry in v:
        new_count_key = new_key + sep + str(counter)
        items.extend(self.flatten(entry, new_count_key, sep=sep).items())
        counter += 1
else:
    items.append((new_key, v))
    if new_key not in self.key_list:
        self.key_list.append(new_key)
```

What if instead you just assume that you have a list, and then work with the dictionary if you don't:

```
try:
    items.append((new_key, v))
    if new_key not in self.key_list:
        self.key_list.append(new_key)

except AttributeError:  # Is a dict, not a list
    counter = 0
    for entry in v:
        new_count_key = new_key + sep + str(counter)
        items.extend(self.flatten(entry, new_count_key, sep=sep).items())
        counter += 1
```

What you're doing here is attempting to `append` to `items` with the assumption that it's a list. If `items` is a dictionary and not a list, then your `except` catches the `AttributeError` that's raised and it will run the code for the dictionary format instead.

The advantage to this, is that you're not detecting the type, you're just catching when it's not a list. That means you spend no time calculating the datatype, you only need to spend time catching the exception when it comes up. This works best if the `except` catches the rarer datatype. So with my proposed solution, if most `items` will be lists then you'll save a lot more time than if most `items` end up being dictionaries.